# How to display a link on the same page in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two controllers Products and Services, which have a has many-belongs to association.I have an 'index.ctp' which displays all my products but I would like to have a link on my 'index.ctp'  which will  display result from another action 'productdisplay' in the  same 'index.ctp' .Is it possible to do this with elements and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### using requestAction()

In CakePHP it's possible to get the rendered action of another Controller/action via `requestAction()`. Read this section of the manual for more information; [Controller::requestAction()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction).

For example;

```
echo $this->requestAction('/products/productdisplay/5');
```

However, requestAction should really be avoided, because it has very poor performance.

### alternatives

#### Using AJAX

Because you mentioned 'when a link is clicked', I'm assuming you're showing a list of products and, when a user clicks a 'detail' button/link, the details of *that* product should be shown.

The best way for this is to use JavaScript (AJAX) to retrieve the information from the productdisplay action.

#### Using elements

If you don't want to rely on JavaScript, and want the productdisplay content to be included 'statically' in the page, you may consider creating an 'element' for this. Elements are 'partial views' that can be embedded in your views. However, if an element makes use of data from your Models, you'll have to retrieve that data and pass it to the view;

Read this section of the manual for more information on elements: [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)

In your controller:

```
public function index($selectedProductId = null)
{
    // retrieve all products for the overview
    $this->set('products', $this->Products->find('all'));

    if ($selectedProductId) {
        // a product has been selected,
        // retrieve the data for the selected product
        $this->set('selectedProduct', $this->Products->findById($selectedProductId));
    }

}
```

In your view

```
// render your list of products 
foreach ($products as $product) {
     echo $this->Html->link(
        $product['Product']['name'], 
        array('action' => 'index', 0 => $product['Product']['id'])
     );
}


if (isset($selectedProduct)) {
     // a product has been selected. Render it using an element
     // this will render View/Elements/productDisplay.ctp
     echo $this->element('productDisplay');
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help....we tried all this but it didn't work for us so for now we have directed it to new page